# stderr written to terminal when using |& in if-expression

Tags: bash

I'm writing a shell script and want to carefully control its terminal output since I want to use that for relevant logging.

At one point in this shell script I use |& as part of building an expression to evaluate in an if-statement:

```
if [[ -f $f ]] && ( identify -verbose $f |& grep -q "Corrupt JPEG data" ) ; then
```

The problem is that identify -verbose $f writes to both stdout and stderr. I use |& to pass both stdout and stderr to grep successfully. stdout is not printed to the terminal here, as I desire. But stderr is. If I run the command in isolation at the prompt this does not happen. Why is that? And can it be suppressed?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Joshua

Comment: `But stderr is.`  That must not be stderr, because stderr is redirected to `grep`. What exactly is printed? Is `if` statement relevant to your question?

Comment: `identify -verbose "$f" 2>&1 |` would be a much better way to write this (compatible with standard-compliant shells).

Comment: `|&` is extremely non-portable; it'll either cause an error or do something else in non-bash shells, older versions of bash, and even bash when run under the name `sh`! I'd avoid it (use `2>&1 |` as @CharlesDuffy suggested)  if you want any sort of consistency from your script.

Comment: Thank you all for this suggestion. This is indeed better. But using 2>&1 instead of |& still gives the same issue.

Comment: @KamilCuk if it is not stderr, is there some way to see to what streams/FDs processes are printing? And the if statement is relevant to my question as it does appear to work as I expect outside of if-statements ....

Comment: @JoshuaSchroijen I'd first experiment to see what's important in triggering the problem. If you remove the `[[ -f $f ]] &&`, does it still output to the terminal? What if you remove the `( )` around it? What about if you leave the `( )`, but remove the `if .. then` around *that*? Etc... Also, what's an example error condition that gets written to the terminal (or is it all errors, or what)?

Comment: `is there some way to see to wha` Yes, `strace identify ...`. `as it does appear to work as I expect outside of if-` that would be very strange - `if` does not change anything, it only checks the exit status, any command runs normally.

Comment: Honestly, the easiest way to interpret this is that `Corrupt JPEG data` is not in fact a genuine byte-for-byte match for the string you're trying to match.

Comment: BTW, the parenthesis have a performance cost -- they're not just grouping, they tell the shell to `fork()` off a subprocess and run the code there. If you want something that's just a grouping operator, use curly braces: `if [[ -f $f ]] && { identify -verbose "$f" 2>&1 | grep -q "Corrupt JPEG data"; }; then`

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want to be able to debug what's going on, consider ditching `grep -q` and instead using shell builtins that will have meaningful xtrace logs. For example: `if [[ -f $f ]] && { identify_output=$(identify -verbose "$f" 2>&1) && [[ $identify_output =~ "Corrupt JPEG data" ]]; }; then echo "File exists but is corrupt"; fi` will emit more useful trace logs if run with `bash -x yourscript` or in a script that runs `set -x` as a prior command.

Comment: Everyone, thank you so much for your help. It has taught me a few things. But in the end the problem turned out to be that the same output that could be generated by the command in the if-expression was being generated by a command further down the script whose stderr wasn't redirected correctly.
An embarrassing little mistake :) I thought it was something special because I'm new to shell scripting. Thanks so much for all the help!